# How to select records without duplicate on just one column in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, duplicates

I have a table with 3 columns like this:

```
+------------+---------------+-------+  
| Industry      | country    | price |  
+------------+---------------+-------+  
Retail          |UK              | 20
Retail          | Japan          | 30
Retail          | Germany        | 40
Retail          | America        | 50
```

My desired result is something like this:

```
+------------+---------------+-------+  
| Industry      |    country  | price |  
+------------+---------------+-------+  
Retail         | UK             | 20
               | Japan          | 40
               | Germany        | 40
               | America        | 50
```

I need to have the category Industry without any duplicate. What is the best SQL command to make this?

Comment: This is not how sql works. I suppose you could get very creative with windowing functions and achieve the desired format. Sql isn't meant to format data though. You need to find a reporting tool/package that format the data in the grouping like your desired results show.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following if that works for you. I have added SQL fiddle link as well

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d162a4/10

```
select (case when row_id=1 then industry else ' ' end) industry
        ,country
        ,price
from (select industry,country
            ,price
            ,row_number() over(partition by industry order by rownum) row_id
      from prices
     ) tmp
```

Comment: I kind of understand the answer, but MySQL doesn't have `rownum` so the upvotes baffle me.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, if you check my SQL fiddle I have used oracle 11g and I was not sure from the question what order is the priority and just used rownum and if you know the order priority we can replace rownum with the columns and I believe should work in mysql as well

Comment: . . I am aware that the SQL Fiddle uses Oracle.  The question is tagged "mysql".   I get that you might not be as sensitive to the tags, being a new contributor.  It is the upvotes I do not get.

Comment: take it easy and chill

Answer (score 0):

You really want to do this in the presentation layer.  SQL tables and result sets represent *unordered* sets.  The only exception is when the final result has an `order by`.  So you need to be very careful to protect against rearrangement.

Your data appears to have the lowest price first.  So in MySQL 8+ or almost any other database, you can do:

```
select (case when row_number() over (partition by industry order by price, country) = 1
             then industry
        end) as industry,
       country, price
from t
order by industry, price, country;
```

I cannot tell if the space in the second column is intentional, but you can include it.

Let me repeat:  The outer `order by` is critical to ensuring that the data is as you want it.  Without the result say may "look" right, but it might not work the next time the query is run.

In earlier versions of MySQL, you can do the same thing, but it looks different.  You haven't tagged the version, so I'll assume the more recent version.